# How to define a list in python tkinter mainloop without changing it's value

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, pypdf

I was trying to make a python program for splitting pdfs using [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html). So I had to define a list to append the elements but when the loop iterates again the value of the list changes to a blank list. Therefore the program will make a pdf with nothing in it. Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
  
elements = []
root7 = tk.Tk()
root7.geometry("600x600")
root7.title("PDF Viewer")
root7.configure(bg="#202020")

    
image7 = Image.open("split.jpg")
new_img7 = image7.resize((600,400))
photo7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_img7)


def open1():
    pdf = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("pdf files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))
    elements.append(pdf)

    w = tk.Spinbox(root7, from_=0, to=100, width=3)
    w.place(x=150, y=510)
    elements.append(int(w.get()))

    w1 = tk.Spinbox(root7, from_=0, to=100, width=3)
    w1.place(x=409, y=510)
    elements.append(int(w1.get()))
    
def split():
    pdfs = PdfFileReader(elements[0], "rb")
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    for page in range(elements[1], elements[2]):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdfs.getPage(page))

    output_fname = "splitted.pdf"

    with open(output_fname, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

    messagebox.showinfo("Splitted","PDF Saved in Desktop as splitted.pdf")
    

lbl7 = tk.Label(root7,image=photo7)
lbl7.place(x=0, y=0)

button7 = tk.Button(root7, text= 'Open PDF', command=open1, bg="#B8B8B8")
button7.place(width=300, height=50, x=150, y=450)

button8 = tk.Button(root7, text= 'Split PDF', command=split, bg="#B8B8B8")
button8.place(width=300, height=50, x=150, y=540)


root7.update()
root7.mainloop()
```

Someone please help.

Comment: You only create your page range spinboxes after the PDF file has been selected, and then *immediately* get their values.  You're creating the new file with a page range of 0 to 0; when has the user had any chance to enter anything else?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. When the tkinter.mainloop() runs the loop each time the value of the elements(list) is changed to a blank list. That shouldn't happen. If that will not happen then the program will run successfully. That is why the programs saves the pdf with no pages inside it since the range of the pages to be splitted becomes zero

Comment: I shall change the user interface after fixing this bug.

Comment: See, the thing, its related to event driven programming, means you have to have a button or trigger some sort of event, that will add the value to the list, as of now, what your doing is, your asking them to append the initial value of the spinbox, ie, 0

Comment: Thank you for the information, I was able to solve the problem

Comment: You can either close this Q or you can add your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had finally found the answer. The problem was not with the list, but it was caused when I took the initial value of the spinbox widget, here is the modified code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
  
w = 0
w1 = 0
root7 = tk.Toplevel()
root7.geometry("600x600")
root7.title("PDF Splitter")
root7.configure(bg="#202020")
elements = []

    
image7 = Image.open("split.jpg")
new_img7 = image7.resize((600,400))
photo7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_img7)


def open1():
    global w, w1
    pdf = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("pdf files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))
    elements.append(pdf)

    w = tk.Spinbox(root7, from_=0, to=100, width=3)
    w.place(x=150, y=510)
    

    w1 = tk.Spinbox(root7, from_=0, to=100, width=3)
    w1.place(x=409, y=510)
    elements.append(int(w1.get()))
    
def split():
    global w, w1
    pdfs = PdfFileReader(elements[0], "rb")
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    elements.append(int(w.get()))
    elements.append(int(w1.get()))

    w2 = int(w.get())
    w3 = int(w1.get())

    for page in range(45):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdfs.getPage(w2-1))
        w2+=1
        if (w2-1)==(w3):
            break

    output_fname = "splitted.pdf"

    with open(output_fname, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

    messagebox.showinfo("Splitted","PDF Saved in Desktop as splitted.pdf")
    

lbl7 = tk.Label(root7,image=photo7)
lbl7.place(x=0, y=0)

button7 = tk.Button(root7, text= 'Open PDF', command=open1, bg="#B8B8B8")
button7.place(width=300, height=50, x=150, y=450)

button8 = tk.Button(root7, text= 'Split PDF', command=split, bg="#B8B8B8")
button8.place(width=300, height=50, x=150, y=540)


root7.update()
root7.mainloop()
```

The GUI is not good, but it still works.